# Function prop useEffect best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting a `load` function `prop` from a *connected* container and I'm considering two options to use with `useEffect` but I don't know which one might be considered best practice, here the first one:

```
function MyComponent({ load }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    load();
  }, [load]);
}
```

Here's the second one I've [read about](https://blog.logrocket.com/rethinking-hooks-memoization/) using `useRef`:

```
function MyComponent({ load }) {
  const loadRef = useRef({ loadData: load});

  useEffect(() => {
    const { loadData } = loadRef.current;

    loadData(); 
  }, []);
}
```

Which one should I use and why?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you need to call function load in the beginning, when the component will be mounted?

Comment: @Eugene yes I need to call it once

Answer (score 0):

Using hooks, what you probably want is to use useDispatch()

and call useDispatch(actionCreator) inside the useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a Redux function once?

just use

```js
useEffect(() => {
  load();
}, []);
```

You might not even need to add `load` to the brackets, if the loading doesn't stop that means your component isn't re-rendering after it stops and you need to put the object that tells the life cycle method to re-render because the loading is done, in most cases its an `isLoading` boolean in local state.

Answer (score 0):

To call something once, when the component just mounted, you can use hook useEffect with empty dependencies:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    load()
  }, [])
```

More info https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

The load function can be taken from props, if you will map it from redux via connect function.
More info https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      load();
    }
  []);
```

It is only a callback. You should not pass the load if you would like to call it once.
From the react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html:

> In the example above, we pass [count] as the second argument. What does this mean? If the count is 5, and then our component re-renders with count still equal to 5, React will compare [5] from the previous render and [5] from the next render. Because all items in the array are the same (5 === 5), React would skip the effect. That’s our optimization.

Of course you can use the dispatching through the redux, however i guess in this easy situation dispatching event is a little bit dirty. So in my opinion use of useEffect hook is cleaner.